# Collatz sequence (endless loop)

Tags: python, recursion

Firstly i know this is a very asked question. Write a function named collatz() that has one parameter named number. If
number is even, then collatz() should print number // 2 and return this value.
If number is odd, then collatz() should print and return 3 * number + 1.
Then write a program that lets the user type in an integer and that keeps
calling collatz() on that number until the function returns the value 1.

```
def collatz(number):

  return [number //2 if number %2 == 0 else 3*number + 1]


number = int(input('Number - \n'))

while number != 1:

  result = collatz(number)
  print(result)
```

What i don't understand in my program is why it does the first operation and gets stuck in the first number. Like if i input 12 it returns 6 but gets stuck in the while loop by printing 6 forever. I want to understand what is wrong specifically in this program.

Comment: You never update `number`, so nothing can change. Also, why do you return a list  in `collatz`?

Comment: i thought that was a more compact way to write the if else sequence @ThierryLathuille

Comment: Just remove the `[ ]`, that builds a list containing your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are discarding `result`. You likely mean `number = collatz(number)[0]` (you use a list here for some reason).

Since you are not modifying `number` within your loop, the condition always evaluates to the same value and the input to `collatz` is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not appending new elements to the list but rather replace the list with the current result.
I have modified your code so that the list is filled with the elements from the sequence:

```
n = int(input("n="))
l = []
while n != 1:
  l.append(n);
  n = n // 2 if n % 2 == 0 else n * 3 + 1
print(l)
```